# gets not defined in eval'd script

Tags: ruby, eval

I have a ruby script which I load and eval like so. Below is a simplified example, with extraneous details removed:

`eval_me.rb`:

```
puts 'Hi there! What\'s your name?'
name = gets
puts "Hi, #{name}!"
```

`main.rb`:

```
script = File.read('eval_me.rb')
eval script
```

This results in the horrible exception that `gets` is not defined.

Strangely, changing the `gets` call to `$stdin.gets` works.

1) Why is this?, and
2) What other functions will have similar issues?

---

Additional (probably useless) information: I also tried wrapping everything in `eval_me.rb` inside a method in a class, like so, although it made no difference:

```
class EvalMe
  def execute
    # Same code as before ...
  end
end
```

... and calling it with some fancy reflection (map `eval_me` to `EvalMe`, call `EvalMe.new`, and then call `execute` on that)

... although it resulted in the same error.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue using your example on Ruby 2.0. How are you running `main.rb`? Anything else in there?

Comment: @ZachKemp yes, quite a lot of stuff. I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 on Linux (and Windows). If you're interested, you can fork the repository [here](https://github.com/ashes999/solar) and run `main.rb` like so: `ruby main.rb configure_git_id`. It runs `/server/actions/common/configure_git_id.rb`, which currently uses `$stdin.gets`.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example. in general, you can just pass a string to eval, so inlining the code into a script variable should yield the same result as reading the file. there might be differences with using save-levels of ruby, but that would be a really shitty windows configuration i guess.

Comment: @phoet I thought the script above would repro the problem. If not, it's likely not a Ruby issue, but something that I'm doing. I'll take a look.